# Factory reset when enabling and disabling OEM Unlock in one session?

Tags: factory-reset, bootloader-lock, google-pixel

I accidentally enabled "OEM Unlock" on my old Pixel 3a. I instantly disabled "OEM Unlock" again. Will the phone forcefully factory reset when I reboot?

Comment: OEM Unlock is not the same as bootloader unlocking procedure - it is prerequisite

Comment: No your phone will not perform a factory reset. Enabling that option is just the first step for bootloader unlocking it simply say "I allow bootloader unlocking" but the actual unlocking procedure has to be performed on a different point in system.

Comment: @Robert that's good news. You should write an answer so I can mark it once I verified your statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally decided to restart my phone. Robert was right, no factory reset has happened.